# Como mudar Toolbar ao clique longo de uma ListView

Tags: android, listview

Sou iniciante em programação Android e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida. Tenho uma ListView que está conectado a um banco de dados SQLite. A minha dúvida é: como eu poderia fazer para que quando o usuário desse um clique longo em um item dessa lista uma nova Toolbar aparecesse?

Para exemplificar melhor, vejam as prints.

[image: Toolbar muda quando um item tem um clique longo]

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isto:

```
final GestureDetector detetor = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Clique Longo Detetado");
        //Adicionas a tua ToolBar aqui
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return detetor.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```